# What is the status of the moblin UI mx library?

Tags: user-interface, gnome, clutter

I stumbled upon the [mx ui toolkit](https://blogs.gnome.org/thos/2009/11/18/a-new-clutter-widget-toolkit/) that provides [clutter](https://blogs.gnome.org/clutter/) based high level widgets: think `buttons`, `listviews`, etc but opengl accelerated thanks to clutter.

This library was developed for the moblin/meego platform.

The status of the library is a bit mysterious: while the library [reached 1.0](https://blogs.gnome.org/thos/2010/05/20/mx-toolkit-1-0/) the source hasn't been updated [after 2012](https://gitorious.org/mx-toolkit).

Finding any code sample beyond the [api documentation](http://valadoc.org/#!api=mx-1.0/Mx) is not easy and there is dead links at ever corner, even in the source repository hosted on gitorious (that will close soon).

**What is the status of mx library? Where is the official source repository? Is there any tutorial available?**

> **edit**: the code sits in [clutter's github repository](https://github.com/clutter-project/mx). The last commit 
>   dates back to Sept, 2013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Mx library is completely unmaintained, and it has not been updated past the demise of the MeeGo user experience for netbooks, which is why it was created. Even then, it was not really a general purpose toolkit for applications, but a simple toolkit for implementing the desktop shell. Mx was later used as the toolkit for the [Media Explorer](https://github.com/media-explorer/) project — but, again, it never was meant to be used a general purpose toolkit.

Given its state, Mx has not been updated after the various Clutter deprecations, so it's not entirely guaranteed to work with Clutter ≥ 1.10.